# Conditional ENV in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is it possible to conditionally set an `ENV` variable in a Dockerfile based on the value of a build `ARG`?

Ex: something like

```
ARG BUILDVAR=sad
ENV SOMEVAR=if $BUILDVAR -eq "SO"; then echo "hello"; else echo "world"; fi
```

Update: current usage based on Mario's answer:

```
ARG BUILD_ENV=prod
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN if [ "${BUILD_ENV}" = "test" ]; then export NODE_ENV=development; fi
```

However, running with `--build-arg BUILD_ENV=test` and then going onto the host, I still get

```
docker run -it mycontainer bin/bash
[root@brbqw1231 /]# echo $NODE_ENV
production
```

Comment: Try `RUN if [ "$BUILD_ENV" = "test" ]; then export NODE_ENV=development; fi` . Mind the whitespaces. Do not remove them

Comment: @alkis didn't seem to help though good catch on using `=` instead of `eq`

Comment: Export variable during image build will not expand at run-time of container, instead use `RUN if [ "${BUILD_ENV}" = "test" ] ;then echo BUILD_ENV=development >>/etc/environment ; fi`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to use your build argument as flag. You can use [parameter expansion feature](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) of shell to check condition. Here is a proof-of-concept Docker file:

```
FROM debian:stable
ARG BUILD_DEVELOPMENT
# if --build-arg BUILD_DEVELOPMENT=1, set NODE_ENV to 'development' or set to null otherwise.
ENV NODE_ENV=${BUILD_DEVELOPMENT:+development}
# if NODE_ENV is null, set it to 'production' (or leave as is otherwise).
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-production}
```

Testing build:

```
docker build --rm -t env_prod ./
...
docker run -it env_prod bash
root@2a2c93f80ad3:/# echo $NODE_ENV 
production
root@2a2c93f80ad3:/# exit
docker build --rm -t env_dev --build-arg BUILD_DEVELOPMENT=1 ./
...
docker run -it env_dev bash
root@2db6d7931f34:/# echo $NODE_ENV
development
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution, especially when building something like Nuxt.js/next.js where the NODE_ENV needs to be set at build time, not run time.

Comment: After a little more use with this, there are some caveats to ARG, it is only used for the next stage (line in the dockerfile) so you have to include it multiple times if you want to use it multiple times
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables

Comment: @Sup3rb0wlz That warning is about multi-stage builds i.e. multiple "FROM ..." lines. If you aren't using those then the ARG will continue on all future lines of the Dockerfile.

Comment: Note that variables in Dockerfiles only allow a [limited subset of expansion types](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement), not the whole list in that link (which is for bash, not docker). Basically, the only two types allowed are the + form and – form, which are shown in this answer.

Comment: OMG, I spent half of my day trying to figure out how I can add if/else in `Dockerfile` tried all bash code but still as unsuccessful because there is a difference in syntax of `if` condition. You lines of code just worked perfectly without needing to use `if/esle`. thanks man.

Answer (score 27):

You cannot run bash code in the *Dockerfile* directly, but you have to use the `RUN` command. So, for example, you can change `ENV` with `RUN` and export the variable in the `if`, like below:

```
ARG BUILDVAR=sad 
RUN if [ "$BUILDVAR" = "SO" ]; \
    then export SOMEVAR=hello; \
    else export SOMEVAR=world; \
    fi
```

I didn't try it but should work.

Comment: So, this builds but when I run it the existing ENV isn't overwritten. I updated my question with my usage based on your answer.

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: -eq: not found

Comment: Note that an env var set with `RUN export` won't persist in the resulting image

Comment: @BastienLibersa exported variable will not even persists outside this RUN statement because it is treated as separate layer.

Comment: @holms et al. - keep in mind that for images based on some linux distrubutions, e.g. ubuntu, you have to use the single `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: @RuslanKabalin Exactly, this is why it shouldn't be seen as a replacement to `ENV`

Comment: `==` works in alpine :) Don't set variables this way. But `if` statement is totally valid solution. I have commands which I need to run only in prod environment, so this is perfect.

Comment: This doesn't work `Step 9/11 : RUN if [ "$version" = "show"]; then export runCMD=hello; else export runCMD=world; fi
 ---> Running in 160b291ca7e4
/bin/sh: 1: [: missing ]`

Comment: @PeterWeyand most likely a missing space before the closing bracket `]`

Comment: I only get `[: unexpected operator` in azure pipelines

Comment: You should do it with the same stage where you need the variable with &&.

Comment: This was perfect for setting the options of my ENTRYPOINT command based on various conditions in the build process.

Comment: As mentioned previously, I don't think this persists outside this single run statement.

Answer (score 6):

While you can't set conditional `ENV` variables but you may be able to acomplish what you are after with the `RUN` command and a [null-coalescing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62333/setting-a-shell-variable-in-a-null-coalescing-fashion) environment variable:

```
RUN node /var/app/current/index.js --env ${BUILD_ENV:-${NODE_ENV:-"development"}}
```

Comment: I like this, but it's limited to conditions that can be determined outside of the container (at run time), which is why I'm not going to accept it as "the" answer. I think a full solution to this should be able to work inside of the container (unless it can be shown that that isn't possible). Thanks for the learning regarding null-coalescing in bash though!

Answer (score 6):

Your logic is actually correct.
The problem here is that `RUN export ...` won't work in a Dockerfile because the `export` command won't persist across images.
Dockerfiles create a temporary container in order to generate the image for it, therefore the environment variables won't exist.

`ENV` on the other hand as per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) states:

> The environment variables set using `ENV` will persist when a container is run from the resulting image.

The only way to do this is during your `docker run` command when generating the container from your image, and wrap your logic around that:

```
if [ "${BUILD_ENV}" = "test" ]; then
    docker run -e NODE_ENV=development myimage
else
    docker run myimage
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking only about environment variable, then just set it with production

```
ENV NODE_ENV prod
```

And during container start in development, you may use `-e NODE_ENV=dev`.

This way image is always built-in production but the local container is launched in development.

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51264575/13599017) is great if you only need to check whether a build-arg is present and you want to set a default value.
To improve this solution, in case you want to use the data passed by the build-arg, you can do the following:

```
FROM debian:stable
ARG BUILD_DEVELOPMENT=production
ENV NODE_ENV=$BUILD_DEVELOPMENT
```

The magic comes from the default value for the ARG.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for dockerfile and multi-arch building. If you need more than 2 options for a variable (or argument) you should use another strategy. I exported the variable to file (.env) in one RUN command. After that, I imported this file and used my variable in another RUN command. Let's recap.

```
FROM debian:bullseye as base
ARG TARGETPLATFORM
RUN if [ "$TARGETPLATFORM" = "linux/arm/v7" ] ; then \
      YQ_BINARY="yq_linux_arm"; \
    elif [ "$TARGETPLATFORM" = "linux/amd64" ] ; then \
      YQ_BINARY="yq_linux_amd64"; \
    fi; \
    export YQ_BINARY; \
    env | grep YQ_BINARY >> /etc/profile.d/yq_binary.env
RUN . /etc/profile.d/yq_binary.env \
    && echo "YQ_BINARY: ${YQ_BINARY}"
```

While building this dockerfile as:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7 -t mydockerimage:base -f ./Dockerfile --push --target base .. --progress plain
```

I got:

```
#43 [linux/amd64 base 19/22] RUN . /etc/profile.d/yq_binary.env     && echo "YQ_BINARY: foo"
#43 0.029 YQ_BINARY: yq_linux_amd64
#43 DONE 0.0s

#44 [linux/arm/v7 base 19/22] RUN . /etc/profile.d/yq_binary.env     && echo "YQ_BINARY: foo"
#44 0.051 YQ_BINARY: yq_linux_arm
#44 DONE 0.1s
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Passing values to Dockerfile and then to entrypoint script

From the command line pass in your required value (TARG)

```
docker run --env TARG=T1_WS01 -i projects/msbob
```

Then in your `Dockerfile` put something like this

```
Dockerfile:
# if $TARG is not set then "entrypoint" defaults to Q0_WS01
CMD ./entrypoint.sh ${TARG} Q0_WS01
```

The `entrypoint.sh` script only reads the first argument

```
entrypoint.sh:
#!/bin/bash
[ $1 ] || { echo "usage: entrypoint.sh <$TARG>" ; exit ; }
target_env=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for setting proxy server on a container.

The solution I'm using is an entrypoint script, and another script for environment variables configuration. Using RUN, you assure the configuration script runs on build, and ENTRYPOINT when you run the container.

--build-arg is used on command line to set proxy user and password.

The entrypoint script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Load the script of environment variables
. /root/configproxy.sh
# Run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

configproxy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function start_config {
read u p < /root/proxy_credentials

export HTTP_PROXY=http://$u:$p@proxy.com:8080
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://$u:$p@proxy.com:8080

/bin/cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/apt.conf 
Acquire::http::proxy "http://$u:$p@proxy.com:8080";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://$u:$p@proxy.com:8080";
EOF
}

if [ -s "/root/proxy_credentials" ]
then
start_config
fi
```

And in the Dockerfile, configure:

```
# Base Image
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG user
ARG pass

USER root

# -z the length of STRING is zero
# [] are an alias for test command
# if $user is not empty, write credentials file
RUN if [ ! -z "$user" ]; then echo "${user} ${pass}">/root/proxy_credentials ; fi

#copy bash scripts
COPY configproxy.sh /root
COPY startup.sh .

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", ". /root/configproxy.sh"]

# Install dependencies and tools
#RUN apt-get update -y && \
#    apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
#    vim iputils-ping

ENTRYPOINT ["./startup.sh"]
CMD ["sh", "-c", "bash"]
```

Build without proxy settings

```
docker build -t img01 -f Dockerfile .
```

Build with proxy settings

```
docker build -t img01 --build-arg user=<USER> --build-arg pass=<PASS> -f Dockerfile .
```

Take a look [here](https://github.com/zig999/docker-proxy).