# How to use a local file or retrieve it remotely (conditionally) in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'd like to be able to control the source of a file (Java Archive) in a `Dockerfile` which is either a download (with `curl`) or a local file on the same machine I build the Docker image.

I'm aware of ways to control `RUN` statements, e.g. [Conditional ENV in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057468/conditional-env-in-dockerfile), but since I need access to the filesystem outside the Docker build image, a `RUN` statement won't do. I'd need a conditional `COPY` or `ADD` or a workaround.

I'm interested in built-in Docker functions/features which avoid the use of more than one Dockerfile or wrapping the `Dockerfile` in a script using templating software (those just workarounds popping into my head).

Answer (score -1):

you can use multi-stage build which is rather new in docker:

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: I worked through the capabilities and don't have an idea how a conditional reading from local filesystem (as opposed to the alternative to download an artifact) could be acchieved with multistage builds. Please elaborate.