# How to set docker env variable if not present?

Tags: linux, docker, environment-variables

I mean something like this:

`docker run -e VAR_FINAL=${VAR1} OR ${VAR_DEFAULT} some_awesome_image`

If VAR1 is present then VAR_FINAL=${VAR1} else VAR_FINAL=${VAR_DEAFULT}

Comment: I guess the standard way of doing this is `VAR1=${VAR1:-$DEFAULT_VAR}` not sure with docker though.

Comment: I think this will help [Conditional ENV in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057468/conditional-env-in-dockerfile)

Comment: This is a helpful resource https://manifold.co/blog/arguments-and-variables-in-docker-94746642f64b